# How can I fix error in runnin test in calabash-android?

Tags: android, calabash

I am using Calabash-Android and when I run with this comand:

```
calabash-android run <apk>
```

I am getting this error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'required' in package 'android'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.2/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in calabash_build': Could not create dummy.apk (RuntimeError)
```

Some idea in how to fix this?

My configuration:

- rbenv version 1.9.3-p392
- calabash-android version 0.4.2

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: Which versions of the Android SDK do you have installed? Try to look in $ANDROID_HOME/platforms

Comment: Hi @jonasmaturana These are the SDK that I have installed.
android-3 android-4 android-7 android-8 android-10 android-12 android-14 android-15 android-16 android-17

Comment: @RaghavSood The manifest, in the referred line 8 has the following code:
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" />

Comment: ps: android:required was introduced in API Level 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think installing a newer version of the Android SDK will solve your problem.

`android:required` was introduced pretty late - I think around api level 5.